# Delete result of mongodb $lookup aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How do I delete all the `chunks` documents which are returned as a result of this aggregation?

```
db.getCollection('chunks').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "files",
          localField: "files_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "file"
        }
   },
   {
     $match:
       {
         "file.uploadDate":
           {
             $lt: ISODate("2017-06-10T00:00:00.000Z")
           }
       }
   }
])
```

My schema has a collection named `files`, which contains file metadata (name, uploadDate) and chunks, which contain the actual data (binary, files_id)

I am aware of `db.collection.deleteMany({})` however it accepts only a match filter.

I have MongoDB 3.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loop the results:

```js
var ops = [];

db.getCollection('chunks').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "files",
          localField: "files_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "file"
        }
   },
   {
     $match:
       {
         "file.uploadDate":
           {
             $lt: ISODate("2017-06-10T00:00:00.000Z")
           }
       }
   }
]).forEach(doc => {
  ops = [
    ...ops,
    { "deleteOne": {
       "filter": { "_id": doc._id }   
    }}
  ];
  if ( ops.length >= 1000 ) {
    db.getCollection('chunks').bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }
});

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.getCollection('chunks').bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

Or in environments without ES6:

```js
var ops = [];

db.getCollection('chunks').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "files",
          localField: "files_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "file"
        }
   },
   {
     $match:
       {
         "file.uploadDate":
           {
             $lt: ISODate("2017-06-10T00:00:00.000Z")
           }
       }
   }
]).forEach(function(doc) {

  ops.push({ "deleteOne": { "filter": { "_id": doc._id }  } });

  if ( ops.length >= 1000 ) {
    db.getCollection('chunks').bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }
});

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.getCollection('chunks').bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

Using [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) then you are basically "batching" the requests in lots of 1000. So the actual writes and responses from the database happen only at tha time and not for all entries.

You cannot supply an aggregation pipeline as the query argument to the general `.remove**()` methods. So what you do instead is loop the cursor with an action like this.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention I am using MongoDB v 3.2, which doesn't have the `=>` operator.

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan It should. It doesn't? You might want to check that your shell is not older. Or are you in fact using Robomongo or similar. It's just a simple change to write in `function()` instead. I'll write them in as such now.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanx so much, it helped a lot here :)

Answer (score 7):

After you getting aggregate result you can use `map` function to get all `chunk` *ids* and then you can use `db.collection.remove()` with `$in` operator.

```
var pipeline = [
  {$lookup:{
      from: "files",
      localField: "files_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "file"
    }
  },
  {$match:{
      "file.uploadDate":
      {
        $lt: ISODate("2017-06-10T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  }
];

var cursor = db.chunks.aggregate(pipeline);
var chunkIds = cursor.map(function (chunk) { return chunk._id; });
db.chunks.remove({"_id": { "$in": chunkIds }});
```

Comment: The problem here is with a large number of arguments sent to `$in` the request can very easily break the BSON limit. Realistically the number of arguments should not exceed 1000, or there are likely to be problems. There are even many issues raised on this very site about people trying to do the same thing. This is why we have bulk operations.

Comment: For small range application  this query is good enough when user know the deletion size range is not huge (I think) and yes I agree with you for huge amount data deletion bulk operation is good

Comment: My real point is that you do not actually "gain" anything here. You are "still" looping the results because that is what `.map()` does, and potentially you are filling up RAM because you are building an array. Small or large, when you have a cursor, then use it. When you look at the process as I am demonstrating, if there is only 50 results, then there is still only "one" request made, and very efficiently so. So actually, building an array that can exceed 1000 items, will in fact cost. That is what needs to be considered. And I did.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach, which is a little hacky, is moving the computation to mongodb, instead of running the list via your Node.js application. This would require some temproary changes in the data in the database however.

The simple logic is this:

- Use an aggregation to mark items in the database for deletion
- Send a delete query that removes all the marked items

Note: I am writing the code for the most recent version of mongodb, and the `$merge` step I rely on is available from at least version 4.2, but not 4.0 or earler, according to the documentation. **This answer does not help for version 3.2 which was used in the original question**, but I think it's worth adding it here as this question + answer shows up for searches on the problem in general.

### Mark items for deletion

```js
// .toArray() at the end triggers mongodb to execute the merge step - even though it doesn't return anything.
// await makes sure we wait until all items are marked before continuing.
await db.collection("chunks").aggregate([
  // The lookup and matching as before
  { $lookup: { from: "files", localField: "files_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "files" } },
  { $match: { "files.uploadDate": { $lt: ISODate("2017-06-10T00:00:00.000Z") } } },

  // Remove the files field added by the lookup, no longer needed
  { $removeField: "files" },

  // Mark for deletion by setting a field
  { $set: { __markedForDeletion: true } },

  // Overwrite chunks entries with the deletion marking
  { $merge: { into: "chunks", whenMatched: "replace" } },
]).toArray();
```

### Delete marked items

```js
await db.collection("chunks").deleteMany({ __markedForDeletion: true });
```

The advantage of this approach is that it does not require mongodb serializing and sending data to the Node.js application, and just waits for mongodb to internally execute commands, which is much faster and less error prone than the other answers mentioned here.